# Error while trying make a button collapse/expand Angular Material Nested Tree

Tags: angular, tree, angular-material

I have a Angular Material Nested tree. I'm trying to create a button to expand/collapse, but I'm getting the following error: 
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined`

I have tried it using HTML:

```
<button (click)="ahtree.treeControl.collapseAll()">collapseAll</button>

<button (click)="treeControl.expandAll()">expandAll</button>


<mat-tree #ahtree [dataSource]="AccountRelTypeTreeDataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">
  <!-- This is the tree node template for leaf nodes -->
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
    <li class="mat-tree-node">
      <!-- use a disabled button to provide padding for tree leaf -->
      <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
      <p">{{node.displayName}}</p>
    </li>
  </mat-tree-node>
  // The rest...
  ...
```

Or with typescript:

```
  // Trees:
  @ViewChild('ahtree') ahtree;
  selectedTab = 0;

  // Datasource
  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<TreeNode>(node => node.children);
  DataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<TreeNode>();

  ...

   ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ahtree.treeControl.expandAll();
   }
```

I read https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview#treecontrol, but I still don't seem to get it to work. 
Does anyone know how to do this with a Nested Tree?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't show the full stack trace, but I suppose the error is the same one as described in this [Github ticket](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12469).  The solution given by user devversion worked for me.  See this [anchor](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12469#issuecomment-410441658) in the same ticket.

Comment: Thanks for this Answer referencing GitHub issue #12469.  In August 2022 GuillaumeChata added a very similar approach to that (still Open) Issue, setting both objects to TREE_DATA in the constructor:  `constructor() { this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA; /* work-around to avoid an undefined dataNodes even after ViewInit*/  this.treeControl.dataNodes = TREE_DATA; }`  That was all I needed.  He included ChangeDetectorRef in the constructor in his example but that doesn't appear to be necessary to the solution.